# In Laravel Backpack - Column data in view details and XLS download is truncated

Tags: laravel-backpack

If the column data has approximately more than 50 characters the column gets truncated at around 50.
addColumn function has `'type' => 'text'`

In the end there is `[...]`

This is both in the details pop-up and XLS download.

Question is, can this limit be increased from any configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can! There is a `limit` option on the column for that.

```
    $this->crud->addColumns([
        [
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'type' => 'text',
            'limit' => 150,
        ],
        ...
    ]);
```

Comment: If you want to show the longer text you need to override css rule of no-wrap.