# Removing max character length in laravel backpack's addColumn

Tags: laravel-backpack

In backpack for Laravel, when using the `addColumn` method, the return is capped to 50 characters in order not to display too much information on the listing view of the CRUD.

I'm using `model_function` in order to display a thumbnail. Problem is, when the image's HTML code is larger than 50 characters, the return is cut and therefore not displayed.

```
<img src="http://localhost:8000/images/admin/photo[...] // I'm missing an ID here
```

I've managed to limit the number of characters by calling my route with a relative path, which temporarly solved the issue, but I'm looking for a more future-proof way.

Is it possible to tell backpack not to limit the number of characters on a given column ? Or to adapt the maximum length ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok my bad, I hadn't searched long enough, there was an answer right here : [In Laravel Backpack - Column data in view details and XLS download is truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355899/in-laravel-backpack-column-data-in-view-details-and-xls-download-is-truncated)

So, in `addColumn`, there is the 'limit' parameter, which can be set to anything possible, including `-1` for no limit.